# Docker run go project with mysql container failed

Tags: docker, go

I have build the go project by using `go build -o qnmahjong` . And I build it in docker successfully with `docker build -t qnmahjong .` . But when I execute the command   `docker run -it --rm --name qnmahjong_login --link first-mysql:mysql -p 5001:5001 qnmahjong login` ,
it gives me this error.

```
 <3>WSL (1) ERROR: ConfigInitializeEntry:1554: Failed to mount (null) at /dev as devtmpfs 1
```

I am running this project on Windows with WSL. I have checked the VM, WSL, Hypervisor functions.

And besides, I don't know whether is it okay to use `go build -o qnmahjong` instead of

```
go build -o qnmahjong -ldflags "-X main.branch=git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD -X main.commit=git rev-parse HEAD"
```

I am copying from this project https://github.com/shuimuliang/qnmahjongserver

Comment: your wsl is corrupted or missing something. try re-installing and then run the command again.

Comment: Do I need to rebuild my go project in docker again? Or simply re-execute the command again would be fine?

Comment: in VS code, unmount the ubuntu or any distro that you are using. Try re-installing WSL again.